# (Animation) Setting source and target armature?

Tags: animation, armature

Sorry if it doesn't make sense (still kind of a newbie) but is there a way to set a source and target armature without using a plug-in? And a way to connect them? I tried ctrl+p (choosing 'object') but it didn't work for me.

I'm willing to spend $25 on the plug-in that the person who made the YT tut is selling but I wanted to know if there was a way to do this for free even if it takes more steps before I whip out my wallet. TIA :)

[image: from a youtube tutorial]

Comment: It might help if you added the link to the YT tutorial that you mention into your question!

Comment: sorry! tutorial is this one (https://youtu.be/KQpp0uBbe-g?t=267)

Comment: Sorry but that tutorial uses a third-party addon and models and armatures from an obscure external site. We can only help with questions about Blender and its built-in addons so your question is really off-topic here.